# How do I concatenate to a cell under one column where another column has a certain value?

Tags: pandas

Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'col2': ['1', '2', '3'],
                   })

row = df.index[df['col1'] == 'b'][0]

df.at[row, 'col2'] = ' '.join([df.at[row, 'col2'], 'info'])
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: what are u trying to achieve? an example of ur output would be nice

Comment: edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html)

```
df.col2=df.col2.astype(str)
df.loc[df['col1'].eq('b').idxmax(), 'col2']+=' info'
df
  col1    col2
0    a       1
1    b  2 info
2    c       3
```

Comment: ended up using the code without the idxmax(), more than one occurrence

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.where` with first argument as condition, second as what to replace with if condition is `True` and third when condition is `False`

```
>>> condition = df['col1'] == 'b'
>>> df['col2'] = pd.np.where(condition, df['col2'] + ' info', df['col2'])
>>> df
  col1    col2
0    a       1
1    b  2 info
2    c       3
```

Comment: `df.index[df['col1'] == 'b'][0]` :-), the first item match b~

Comment: I wrote the answer according to the OP's question title. @YOandBEN_W